# Speed up OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, gpu, tbb

I am using OpenCV 2.4 (C++) for line finding on grayscale images. This involves some basic image processing steps like blurring, threshold, Canny edge detector, gradient filter or Hough transformation. I have to apply the line finding algorithm on thousands of images.

Is there a way to speed up the calculation considering the large number of images?

Does one of the following provide help? Intel TBB, IPP or OpenCV GPU?
I heard that OpenCV GPU can speed up calculations but data transfer is slowly. So using GPU might not be the right choice here?

Thank You!

EDIT:

Is there any sense in using parallel_for from TBB to speed up image processing? If I use a for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<image_location.size();++i)
{
Mat img=imread(image_location[i]);
blur(img...);
threshold(img...);
...
}
```

Can I improve performance by using parallel_for instead? Can anyone provide examples how to use parallel_for including some opencv operations?

Answer (score 2):

The scope of your question is virtually unbounded.

First of all, have you measured the performance of your application to detect the actual bottleneck(s) ? My guess would be the Hough transform, but who knows what else your code is doing. Now, if the Hough transform is the slow piece, and supposing OpenCV has a fast implementation of it, then this is the reason I tell you the question is problematic. Changing for a somewhat better implementation doesn't help much when you decide to increase your already large number of images, the problem is in the approach itself.

Do you really need to use Hough ? Maybe you could achieve something similar/better using morphological operators ? Are the images from some common domain ? Can you include examples of them ? Etc, etc.

Comment: Isn't there any typical approach to deal with a large number of images? i am not looking for a solution which speeds up the calculation a few milliseconds per image. i wonder if there is an appraoch which speeds up the calculation maybe two times or more. I don't need any code examples at the moment, but what do you guys think of gpu, ipp, tbb for a large number of images problem? Since my image processing code is relatively basic and don't think the code itself is the problem but the large number of images.

Comment: A typical approach to deal with a large number of images could be sampling this large amount, but this does not seem to fit your case. Another one would be to throw more computing power at it. Also, I don't understand why you say your code is relatively basic, each OpenCV line of code can imply in a lot of processing. I have seen papers describing huge improvements when moving to GPU, but in the end when you move from thousands images to millions of images you hit the same problem.